# Database table, display a specific image if the value is Not Null

Tags: php

In my database I want 1 specific field to display 1 of 2 images.  If the field contains no text value, then the image displayed is a blank png, that is actually named   .png     , this does work and displays correctly
However if the field contains any other value, text or numeric, any length then I want image 2 to be displayed.  Since I cannot name an image *.png   (windows won't allow this naming convention) is there a way to make this happen.

Here is my current php for that specific column

```
<img src="backgrounds2/<?= $rows['info'] ?>.png" border="0">
```

The table value is called info
thank you

Comment: So give the images sensible names and the issue goes away

Comment: the problem is it is a text field and any value can be entered into it...impossible to have an image for all

Comment: No I mean give BOTH the 2 images sensible names

Comment: What's the reasoning for not just calling them `blank.png` and `text.png` ?

Comment: reasoning was I was not/am not smart enough to realize the easy method of proper syntax that you provided.  Looking at the problem from amateur eyes, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the images `blank.png` and `text.png` then

```
<img src="backgrounds2/<?php if (strlen($rows['info']) == 0){echo 'blank';}else{echo 'text';} ?>.png" border="0">
```

Or give them any sensible(valid) name that makes sense to you

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        $host ="localhost";
        $uname = "root";
        $pwd = '123456';
        $db_name = "master";

        $file_path = 'photo/';
        $result = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Could not connect to database." .mysqli_error());
        mysqli_select_db($result,$db_name) or die("Could not select the databse." .mysqli_error());
        $image_query = mysqli_query($result,"select img_name,img_path from image_table");
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($image_query))
        {
            $img_name = $rows['img_name'];
            if (empty($img_name))
            $img_name = ' No Image  found';
            $img_src = $rows['img_path'];
            if (empty($img_src))
            $img_name = '/nlank.png';
        ?>

        <div class="img-block">
        <img src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $img_name; ?>" width="300" height="200" class="img-responsive" />
        <p><strong><?php echo $img_name; ?></strong></p>
        </div>

        <?php
        }
    ?>
```